# Drawing a rectangle with mouse position in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am currently working on a project where the user is able to draw a rectangle based on the mouse's position. I have this so far but the problem is that once the mouse is released, the rectangle disappears. I think I need to use `mouseReleased` but I'm not sure exactly what to put in it.

Here's my code so far:

```js
var x;
var y;
var x2;
var y2;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
   x2 = mouseX;
   y2 = mouseY;
  background(255);
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    rectMode(CORNERS);
   rect(x, y, x2, y2);
  
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  x = mouseX;
  y = mouseY;
}

function mouseReleased() {
    
  
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list to store the drawn rectangles:

```js
var rectangles = []
```

Add the rectangle to a list when the mouse is released:

```js
function mouseReleased() {
    rectangles.push({x: x, y: y, x2: x2, y2: y2})
}
```

Draw all the rectangles in the list in every frame:

```js
for (let i=0; i < rectangles.length; ++i) {
    let r = rectangles[i]
    rect(r.x, r.y, r.x2, r.y2)
}
```

```js
var x, y, x2, y2;
var rectangles = []

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  rectMode(CORNERS);
}

function draw() {
    x2 = mouseX;
    y2 = mouseY;
    background(255);
    noFill()
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        rect(x, y, x2, y2);
    }
    for (let i=0; i < rectangles.length; ++i) {
        let r = rectangles[i]
        rect(r.x, r.y, r.x2, r.y2)
    }
}

function mousePressed() {
    x = mouseX;
    y = mouseY;
}

function mouseReleased() {
    rectangles.push({x: x, y: y, x2: x2, y2: y2})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```